# BitBucket oauth save token

Tags: php, oauth, bitbucket

I am using the BitBucket API through oAuth to create repositories on behalf of the team. I have set up the API to request oauth access through bitbucket and retrive the access token of the current logged in user. However, calling the api through that will create the repositories under the current user and not the team. I have the credentials for the team login but do not wish to share that.

Is there a way that I can save the access token from the team login so that the repositories will be created under the team?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this answer is generic to the implementation of OAUTH protocol.

OAuth consumers can be issued client ID's and Admin PINs.Using the combination of two access tokens can be issued as a response to API calls.